# ASP.Net MVC3 Html.PasswordFor does not populate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my view I have the following element

```
  @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
```

This is on a screen that creates/updates user details. When I am trying to update the user this field remains blank. When I change this element to a TextBoxFor it gets the data. How do I get to populate the Password field.

Comment: If you have the user's password to be able to put in the box, you have committed an (almost) unforgivable evil.

Comment: I think a valid case for this is if you want the password field to show dots or no dots to indicate whether a password already exists or not. When populating your model you could say `model.Password = String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password) ? "" : "********";`, but `PasswordFor` won't use the value. So you can't give an indication of whether a value exists.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is as designed. Passwords are not filled to prevent accidental resubmits, and to prevent the page from containing unencrypted passwords. Obviously the password was wrong to begin with if you're posting back the credentials.

In your case, you could create an extension that does input the data, or just use an HTML input of type password.

Answer (score 158):

As described above, it is better to avoid doing this for security reason. if you still want to persist the password so that you proceed from where the current validation failed, you can use the HTML helper with html attribute parameter:

```
     Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { value = Model.Password})
```

Comment: this answer is actually answering the question!

Comment: +1 for answering the question.  A good use case for this is registration forms when the error (i.e. username availability being checked on the server side) had nothing to do with the password fields.  I agree it should not be used on log in forms (wouldn't be very useful for the user anyways).

Comment: It's bad because your password is then cached client-side.

Comment: I worked with a dummy password.
After submitting the dummy password a check makes sure the dummy password isn't saved to the database

Comment: It is *telling* that the majority of upvotes for this question go to the answer which introduces a security vulnerability in to an application. I urge each of you to condsider: Do you truly need to display a password? What flaw in your security requires you to display a password in any way? Would you trust an application which was able to reproduce your password and show it back to you? I truly hope not, but perhaps that is why identity theft is such a large problem. When you're dealing with passwords, you are dealing with people's livelihood in quite a literal way.

Comment: I think one thing a number of people like Christopher Harris are skipping over is that "password fields" are not only used for user passwords. I might not want to show a password or token string back on display, but I do want or need to store it unhashed.

Comment: this answer is the real answer!

Answer (score 7):

MVC protects you from doing something like this for a reason.  You shouldn't actually be able to do this because the users password should not be stored unencrypted and unhashed. If your goal is to end end up on http://plaintextoffenders.com/ though, you can do something like:

```
<input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" value="@Model.Password" />
```

Comment: regarding plaintextoffenders, nice site but their "comments" section text is barely visible. check this out:http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/  .. maybe it's a pun?!

Answer (score 1):

I found this workaound. I needed my password shown in the form:

```
@model User
@{
    @Html.Label(Model.Username, new { @class = "label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })

    @Html.Label(Model.Password, new { @class = "label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Password, new { @class = "form-control make-pass" })
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".make-pass").attr("type", "password");
</script>
```

This will make your input password-type without losing the value.

Comment: It's cool! You can put the script in your `Site.js` and use it in any password (that was my requirement)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, its by design. But that can be wrong. We just got a new user who was confused by the empty password after the page refresh when he just added a password. So a simple fix is to change the label 'Password' to 'New password'. Now its clear why this input box is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **asp-for attribute** you can also do:

<input type="password" placeholder="@(Model.Password != null ? String.Concat(Model.Password.ToCharArray().Select(p=>"*")) : "Password")" asp-for="Password">