# Field password returned empty to view in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've MVC5 application and in the create view i have user and password fields.

I put values in the user and password field and when I enter to edit mode i see just the user value in the text box

and the password field is empty,why?

when I debug the code I see that in the end of the edit (   return View(UserPass); ) i got the object with the values and than it call to the view(razor) and I dont see the value in the pass text box ...

Any idea why the user is exist and password not?
I just want it to be **field with asterisks in the edit mode**...

In the edit and the create view  I use:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC3 Html.PasswordFor does not populate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642849/asp-net-mvc3-html-passwordfor-does-not-populate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passwords are not prepopulated to prevent accidential submits and not to have un encrypted passwords.

check below link.

[ASP.Net MVC3 Html.PasswordFor does not populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642849/asp-net-mvc3-html-passwordfor-does-not-populate)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password,new{@Value=Model.Password})
```

Notice that `Value:v` should be uppercase

Comment: very easy solution who wants to show the password already filled any how irrespective of security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering the value of a password into the html source is a huge security risk. Its preventing you from leaking your passwords. Otherwise someone could view the page source and see:

```
<input type="password" value="password123" />
```

I would recommend doing the following:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { placeholder = "********" })
```

This will put some 'visual' asterisks in the textbox which will disappear when the user starts entering an actual value. Its not supported by all browsers, but its something.